# c# and regex : capture a word knowing its position

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this :

```
x|x|x|x|x|x
```

where x can be any word of any size composed of any characters except the separator |.

I would like to know, how can I capture the third word.

For example :

I would like to obtain from the following string :

```
 alex|jim|tim|john|kevin|david
```

This :

```
tim
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `yourstring.Split('|')[2]`

Comment: Reminds me of KISS principle.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like below:

```
string testString = "x|x|abc|x|x|x";

testString.Split('|')[pos]
```

`pos` will be the position number that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a delimited string, no regex needed. Just use:

```
var names = "alex|jim|tim|john|kevin|david";
Console.WriteLine(names.Split('|')[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"alex|jim|tim|john|kevin|david".Split('|')[2]
```

This would **directly** return the third name.